# Unable to use properties of custom defined struct

Tags: c++, struct, header

I have a struct defined like so in my header:

```
struct AABB2 {
    Float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
    AABB2(Float xMin_ = Float(0.0f), Float xMax_ = Float(0.0f), Float yMin_ = Float(0.0f), Float yMax_ = Float(0.0f)) :
        xMin(xMin_), xMax(xMax_), yMin(yMin_), yMax(yMax_) {}
};
```

and in the cpp file I have a function like this :

**EDIT:**
Sorry I posted the wrong function the first time!

```
AABB2 combineAABB(const AABB2 &aabb1, const AABB2 &aabb2) {
    AABB2 aabb;
    aabb.xMin = std::min(aabb1.xMin, aabb2.xMin);
    aabb.xMax = std::max(aabb1.xMax, aabb2.xMax);
    aabb.yMin = std::min(aabb1.yMin, aabb2.yMin);
    aabb.yMax = std::max(aabb1.yMax, aabb2.yMax);
    return aabb;
}

AABB2 combineAABB(const AABB2 &aabb1, const AABB2 &aabb2, const AABB2 &aabb3, const AABB2 &aabb4) {
    AABB2 aabbA = combineAABB(aabb1, aabb2);
    AABB2 aabbB = combineAABB(aabb3, aabb4);
    return combineAABB(aabbA, aabbB);
}


// the call to the combine function

 vector<AABB2> &angularBBRow = angularBBLayer[i];

for (int j = 0; j < currentWidth; j++) {
                AABB2 aabb1 = angularBB[currentLayer - 1][i * 2 + 0][j * 2 + 0];
                AABB2 aabb2 = angularBB[currentLayer - 1][i * 2 + 1][j * 2 + 0];
                AABB2 aabb3 = angularBB[currentLayer - 1][i * 2 + 1][j * 2 + 1];
                AABB2 aabb4 = angularBB[currentLayer - 1][i * 2 + 0][j * 2 + 1];

        angularBBRow.push_back(combineAABB(aabb1, aabb2, aabb3, aabb4));
}
```

but for some reason why I try to call this function to actually use it I get an error message saying **error: ‘mitsuba::AABB2’ has no member named ‘xMin’**

**EXTRA INFO:**

mitsuba is a rendering engine that I am trying to implement this in and so that's why it is present in the error message.

Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Comment: `AABB2` doesn't even appear in your `distSqrPeriod2` function.

Comment: Sorry about that! I posted the wrong function the first time! It's been a long day 

Comment: Why are the keywords *float* and *vector* starting with a capital letter?

Comment: I did a typedef higher up in the file
```typedef float Float;
typedef Eigen::Vector2f Vector2;```

Comment: You should post a more complete example.  These extracts that you have pulled out do not explain the error message you are getting.  Do you define `AABB2` somewhere else?  Is this the _first_ error message?  Pay attention to the error which mentions the namespace `mitsuba`.  Show how and where you use that namespace.

Comment: We can't help you with the code we can't see.

Comment: Sorry about that! I really appreciate all the feedback! I added a little more info to the question and hopefully, that explains my problem a little better?  If not please let me know and I would love to provide more info.

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious now what the problem is.  I will write an answer.

Comment: `combineAABB` expects 2 parameters, while you're passing four!

Comment: I have overloaded the function with this but it just calls the one posted above so I didnt think I needed to include it

Comment: @paddy That is the reason I voted to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mitsuba rendering engine defines its own type for `AABB2`:

```
typedef TAABB<Point2> AABB2
```

It is clear that the error message is referring to this type, which lives in the `mitsuba` namespace.  When the compiler tries to resolve the type of `AABB2` it is picking up mitsuba's version, not yours.

While you haven't shown adequate code despite our efforts in requesting it, there's a high likelihood that you are doing one of the following:

- forgetting to include your header that defines `AABB2`
- importing the entire mitsuba namespace with a call such as `using namespace mitsuba;`
- defining `AABB2` in your own namespace and forgetting to specify that in your type

You may well fix the problem by addressing these points.  Alternatively, you could try renaming your struct to something that is not used by mitsuba.